# Linear regression using sklearn array issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Just trying to set up a simple linear regression test based on the following [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html).

Here is my code:

```
# Normalize customer data
x_array = np.array(CustomerRFM['recency'])
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize([x_array])
y_array = np.array(CustomerRFM['monetary_value'])
normalized_Y = preprocessing.normalize([y_array])

print('normalized_X: ' + str(np.count_nonzero(normalized_X)))
print('normalized_Y: ' + str(np.count_nonzero(normalized_Y)))

X_train, X_test = train_test_split(normalized_X, test_size=0.2)
Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(normalized_Y, test_size=0.2)

print('X_train: ' + str(np.count_nonzero(X_train)))
print('Y_train: ' + str(np.count_nonzero(Y_train)))

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

I have added the four `print()` lines as I am getting a strange issue.  The console print of these four lines is:

```
normalized_X: 4304
normalized_Y: 4338
X_train: 0
Y_train: 0
```

For some reason when I am splitting the data between training and testing data I get no values?

I get the following error on the `regr.fit()` line:

> ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 4339)) while a
>   minimum of 1 is required.

This tells me there is something wrong with the X values but I don't know what

UPDATE: Change to print(array.shape)

If I change my code to use

```
print('normalized_X: ' + str(normalized_X.shape))
print('normalized_Y: ' + str(normalized_Y.shape))
```

and this:

```
print('X_train: ' + str(X_train.shape))
print('Y_train: ' + str(Y_train.shape))
```

I get:

```
normalized_X: (1, 4339)
normalized_Y: (1, 4339)
```

and this:

```
X_train: (0, 4339)
Y_train: (0, 4339)
```

Comment: Before counting for non zero values, did you just `print (X_train)` and `print (Y_train)` to see what's inside

Comment: @Bazingaa - looks like their both empty arrays.

Comment: more helpful than `print(np.count_nonzero(array))` would be `print(array.shape)`. `count_nonzero` will flatten dimensions and ignore zero values - two features that are counterproductive here. shape is where a lot of tricky exciting things happen

Comment: but I don't understand why as both normalized X and Y have data

Comment: Can you try `X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(normalized_X, normalized_Y, test_size=0.2)` and see if `X_train` and `Y_train` are still empty

Comment: @waterproof - updated as requested.

Comment: @Bazingaa - same result.

Comment: I should add that CustomerRFM is a dataframe from a excel file

Comment: X_train, X_test = train_test_split(np.transpose(normalized_X), test_size=0.2)
Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(np.transpose(normalized_Y,) test_size=0.2)

Comment: try changing the two lines as mentioned in the last comments

Comment: Are you trying to scale your data? Then `normalize` does not do what you think it do. You probably need `preprocessing.scale`. In addition to that, follow the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `preprocessing.normalize` incorrectly. By wrapping `[x_array]` in square brackets, you're creating an array of shape `(1, 4339)`.

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html), `preprocessing.normalize` expects an array of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`. In your example, `n_samples` is 1 and `n_features` is 4339 which I don't think is what you want! You're then asking `train_test_split` to split a data set of one sample, so it understandably returns an empty array.